# Can't use pop([i][j]) on a two dimension list, returns IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add new functions to a script I'm developping to learn Python which scraps boxscores from internet and create an excel file.
I would like the users to be able to remove some columns they do not need. Here I've been using two generic lists header, which contains well the header, and stat, which is a two dimension list similar to a stats line.

```
header = ['N°', 'Nom', 'Height', 'Position']
stats = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

I use the list 'to_pop' to collect the index the user wants to remove and then use header.pop(to_pop[i]) where to_pop hold the index I want to delete.

However trying to do the same thing on the 2 dimension list doesn't work as I get the 'IndexError: list index out of range' message.
On the first loop print(stats[i][count]) returns the good value (2) but stats.pop([i][count]) wont work. I even tried switching the variable 'count' with 2 directly but it keeps giving me the same error.

```
 def pop_columns(header, stats):
    to_pop = input('Which columns do you want to delete ? \nPut a comma between each column # to delete \nColumn(s) to delete: ')
    to_pop = to_pop.split(",") 
    to_pop = [int(i) for i in to_pop]
    to_pop.sort(reverse = True)

    for j in range(len(to_pop)):
        count = to_pop[j]

        header.pop(to_pop[j])   

        for i in range(len(stats)):
            print(stats[i][count])
            stats.pop([i][count])
```

[EDIT: Traceback of the error]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_list_input.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_list_input.py", line 44, in main
    header, stats = choose_columns(header,stats)
  File "test_list_input.py", line 34, in choose_columns
    header, stats = pop_columns(header,stats)
  File "test_list_input.py", line 15, in pop_columns
    stats.pop([i][count])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Anyone could help me with this ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe you mean `stats[i].pop(count)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your use of the `for` loop is sub-optimal, which is common in beginners (especially those from other languages). In many languages a `for` loop varies an integer loop variable that is then used to subscript the sequence (usually an array) being iterated over. In Python the successive values of the loop variable *are* the elements of the sequence, meaning there is no need to use subscripting. This avoids an unnecessary level of subcripting, simplifies the code and improves readability.

```
def pop_columns(header, stats):
    to_pop = input('Which columns do you want to delete ? \nPut a comma between each column # to delete \nColumn(s) to delete: ')
    to_pop = to_pop.split(",") 
    to_pop = [int(i) for i in to_pop]
    to_pop.sort(reverse = True)

    for popper in to_pop:
        count = popper

        header.pop(popper)   

        for stat in stats:
            print(stats[count])
            stat.pop([count])
```

When I got to the last statement it was impossible to translate, and it occurred to me that you might have written

```
    stats.pop([i][count])
```

when you actually meant

```
    stats[i].pop(count)
```

since that was the only way the code made sense to me.

The list `pop` method looks for the item given as an argument in the list, removing and returning it if found. The way you wrote the statement your argument to `pop` was a subscripted list `[i][count]`. Since the list only contains the single element `i`, unless the value of `count` is zero the expression would raise an `IndexError` exception.

In future, please try to include the full error message and Python's traceback, since these are *extremely* helpful in finding out what's gone wrong, and would have allowed me to confirm the guesses I've had to make to write this answer so far. This is how it helps ...

Unfortunately, running the code shows that it still isn't correct:

```
In [3]: pop_columns(['N°', 'Nom', 'Height', 'Position'],
   ...:             [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
Which columns do you want to delete ?
Put a comma between each column # to delete
Column(s) to delete: 1,2
[9, 10, 11, 12]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-af711e454e0e> in <module>
      1 pop_columns(['N°', 'Nom', 'Height', 'Position'],
----> 2             [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])

<ipython-input-1-752e7cc7aba6> in pop_columns(header, stats)
     12         for stat in stats:
     13             print(stats[count])
---> 14             stat.pop([count])

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This tells me (and any other reader) that the problem is with the final statement. Alas in rewriting the `pop` I should have taken the subscripts off the argument, since it now represents the value to be popped rather than being a subscript.

Correcting the typo so line 14 reads

```
                stat.pop(count)
```

gives a much more satisfactory result.

```
In [5]: pop_columns(['N°', 'Nom', 'Height', 'Position'],
   ...:             [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
Which columns do you want to delete ?
Put a comma between each column # to delete
Column(s) to delete: 1,2
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[5, 6, 8]
[5, 6, 8]
[5, 8]
```

though I can't absolutely guarantee it's what you wanted to see.

Comment: Maybe also add a section where you show what's the result if you remove the superfluous assignment and fix the pop call?

Comment: What, you mean I have to _run_ it ;-)

Comment: Edited. Better?

Comment: Not exactly what I was thinking but I think it you made it very clear now what the right solution is and why :)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer ! Could you clarify what you mean by " Rather than generating a sequence of indexes and applying them in the body of the loop, Python can bind the items of a sequence directly to a variable." ? English isn't my native language and I am quite new to Python so I might no get the details in your answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry. What I meant was that in many languages a `for` loop varies an integer loop variable, which is then used to subscript the sequence (usually an array) being iterated over. In Python the successive values of the loop variable are the elements of the sequence, meaning there is no need to use subscripting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `stats[i].pop(count)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You are probably correct, but the way you phrased this would more usually have been entered as a comment rather than a full answer.

Comment: It seems like you are asking a question in the answers section... Either [edit] this to be more of an answer, or delete this answer and as a comment